# Error handling in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am developing a REST API using play framework. I would like to implement a centralized error handling for all my actions.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you look at Scala Future and Play action/result before?

Comment: @applicius: I am not quite sure how your comment explains where is the right place to perform *centralized* error handling in a play application...

Comment: I'm quite not sure you have read Play framework doc about Action, Action composition, Action build and use of Future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at the `GlobalSettings`: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal

Especially, it allows you to override:

```
def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable)
def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader)
def onBadRequest(request: RequestHeader, error: String)
```

`onError` is probably the one you are looking for, but the others may be useful too :)

Answer (score 6):

An alternative way do this is to use a [filter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaHttpFilters), e.g:

```
object ExceptionFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(nextFilter: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {
      val next: Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result] = nextFilter(requestHeader)

      // Say your backend throws an ItemNotFound exception.
      next recoverWith {
        case e: ItemNotFound => Iteratee.ignore[Array[Byte]]
          .map(_ => Results.NotFound("Item not in the database!"))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then hook that up in your global settings:

```
object Global extends WithFilters(CSRFFilter(), ExceptionFilter) with GlobalSettings
```

This potentially allows you to do something with the request body if needed. I agree in most cases using `GlobalSettings.onError` is probably the easiest approach.