# Handling exceptions in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using play framework (2.3.x) for building a restful API.

Today I have a try/catch block surrounding all my api functions in the API controller, to be able to catch the exceptions and return a generic "error json" object.

Example:

```
def someApiFuntion() = Action { implicit request =>
    try {
        // Do some magic
        Ok(magicResult)
    } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
            InternalServerError(Json.obj("code" -> INTERNAL_ERROR, "message" -> "Server error"))
    }
}
```

My question is: is it necessary to have a try/catch thingy in each api function, or is there a better/more generic way of solving this?

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547795/error-handling-in-play-framework

Answer (score 5):

@Mikesname link is the best option for your problem, another solution would be to use [action composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaActionsComposition) and create your action (in case you want to have a higher control on your action):

```
def APIAction(f: Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
  Action { request =>
    try { f(request) } 
    catch { case _ => InternalServerError(...) }
  }
}

def index = APIAction { request =>
  ...
}
```

Or using the more idiomatic Scala `Try`:

```
def APIAction(f: Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
  Action { request =>
    Try(f(request))
      .getOrElse(
        InternalServerError(Json.obj("code" -> "500", "message" -> "Server error"))
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: I added the above code into my `Project` but it shows `not found: value APIAction`

Comment: `class LoginWS(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = APIAction { request
    case json_req: JsObject =>
    
        ..............//my code
  .............
        out ! Json.toJson(JsObject(Seq("login_status" -> JsString(login_status), "user_id" -> JsNumber(userID))))
    
      
  }
  
}`

Answer (score -3):

You could wrap any unsafe result in a future, having thus a `Future[Result]`, turning action into async.

```scala
def myAction = Action async Future(Ok(funcRaisingException))
```