# Error when using Try/Catch in Play Framework with Websocket

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, try-catch, playframework-2.3

I am using web sockets with Play Framework in Scala. I would like to use `Try/Catch` functionality in my project for catching some `Exceptions` like `Server Exception`, `Network Exception` and etc.

What I did :

*WebSocketController.scala*

```
object LoginWS {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new LoginWS(out))
}

class LoginWS(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = { 
    case json_req: JsObject =>
      var user_name = (json_req \ "user_name").as[String]
      var password = (json_req \ "password").as[String]
      var source = (json_req \ "source_type").as[String]
      var result = UserLogin.authenticateUser(user_name, password).isDefined
      var userID: Int = 0;
      if(result) {
        userID = UserLogin.getUserRole(user_name, password)
        val login_status : String = "Success"            
        out ! Json.toJson(JsObject(Seq("login_status" -> JsString(login_status), "user_id" -> JsNumber(userID))))
      }
      else {
        val login_status : String = "Failure"
        out ! Json.toJson(JsObject(Seq("login_status" -> JsString(login_status), "user_id" -> JsNumber(userID))))
      }
  }      
}  

object WebSocketController extends Controller {            
  def login = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request => 
    out => LoginWS.props(out)
  }   
}
```

What I tried :

I have used [this answer posted by Ende Neu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574643/handling-exceptions-in-play-framework/25575453#25575453) but it shows `not found: value APIAction`. Note: I added APIAction in *routes* file too

Code :

```
class LoginWS(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = APIAction { request
    case json_req: JsObject =>
     .....
     ....//code here
  }

}
object WebSocketController extends Controller {

  def login = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    out => LoginWS.props(out)
  } 

  def APIAction(f: Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = 
    Action { request =>
      Try(f(request))
        .getOrElse(
          InternalServerError(Json.obj("code" -> "500", "message" -> "Server error"))
        )
    }    
}
```

Please help me to implement Try/Catch functionality in `Web socket`

Comment: Actions are used inside controllers, not actors, actor would just handle messages and receive has to be a partial function, not an Action

Comment: So how can I do a `error` handling `operations` in Action `login` as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login request is handled within actor and I think you should handle your errors there. If you want to catch all exceptions instead of explicitly handling what could go wrong, I suggest doing the following

```
object SomeUtils {
  def catchAll[A](out: ActorRef)(f: => A): Unit = {
    val message = Try(f).getOrElse(Json.obj("code" -> "500", "message" -> "Server error"))
    out ! message
  }
}


import SomeUtils._

class LoginWS(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case json_req: JsObject => catchAll(out) {
      val userName = (json_req \ "user_name").as[String]
      val password = (json_req \ "password").as[String]
      val authenticated = UserLogin.authenticateUser(userName, password).isDefined
      if (authenticated) {
        val role = UserLogin.getUserRole(userName, password)
        Json.obj("login_status" -> "Success", "result" -> role)
      }
      else {
        Json.obj("login_status" -> "Failure", "result" -> 0)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When handling `jsonReq` use catchAll method that would expect to get a receiver of the result and this result that could throw an `Exception`. In case of `Exception` it would use a default message with internal server error, and send this message to the receiver.

You could also make the `out` parameter implicit to skip putting it everywhere. Also your code is not really in scala style. Using `vars` etc...

If json sent to WS couldn't be parsed it would throw exception before reaching your code, solution can be found here:

[How do I catch json parse error when using acceptWithActor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006968/how-do-i-catch-json-parse-error-when-using-acceptwithactor)

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: I modified your changes with my code It doesn't show any error but if I send the values in request it is not sending any response message.before including your code it shows response as
`{ "login_status":"Success","user_id":21}`

Comment: I changed my answer, as I noticed WebSockets does not return `Result` but in your case JsValue.

Comment: I updated with your changes but now it is always returning error `RESPONSE: {"code":"500","message":"Server error"}` even though we sent a correct request.

Comment: Well, I am not sure what reason might be. Maybe I am missing something. Maybe I ruined your code, maybe put your version back inside `catchAll`. Maybe exception is thrown during execution of this, if it does you can check what happens maybe by replacing catchAll implementation to `val message = try f catch { case NonFatal(e) => Json.obj("code" -> "500", "message" -> s"${e.getClass.toString}: ${e.getMessage}") }; out ! message`

Comment: `RESPONSE: {"code":"500","message":"class play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))"}`
above is the error message what I get.

Comment: Well looks to me like parsing error. I don't know. Maybe try to go from your original solution, make sure it works and try to slowly refactor and see when it stops working.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts,I will check and if you find the solution please post here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91626/discussion-between-jamal-and-lukasz).

Comment: It is working now after adding your updated answer.Thanks lot.